# Using a Running total to limit rows selected

Tags: sql, selection, cumulative-sum

I need to stop selecting records when my running total reached 5000.  Below is my query that does produce the needed running total.  Is it possible to use this total in the way I want?  Thanks.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT sddoco AS DocNo, sduorg as OrdQty, sdlitm AS EAN

FROM [QADTA].[f4211]

WHERE sdmcu = '        1070'
    )
SELECT DocNo, OrdQty, EAN
   ,SUM(OrdQty) OVER (ORDER BY DocNo ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeQty
   ,SUM(OrdQty) OVER (ORDER BY DocNo RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeSumByRange

FROM CTE

ORDER BY DocNo, EAN
```

Id like to be able to add where CumulativeQty <= 5000 so I only selected record up until the total reached 5000.

Comment: Write an outer query that selects from your current query and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
with . . .
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT DocNo, OrdQty, EAN,
             SUM(OrdQty) OVER (ORDER BY DocNo ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeQty
             SUM(OrdQty) OVER (ORDER BY DocNo RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeSumByRange
      FROM CTE
     ) t
WHERE t.CumulativeQty <= 5000
ORDER BY DocNo, EAN;
```